# Error RVIZ extrapolation into the future on the same machine

Tags: ros, lidar, ros2, rviz, ros-humble

I get the following error when trying to view my [RPLidar](https://github.com/babakhani/rplidar_ros2) A2 scan in rviz2. It’s on a differential drive robot controlled using Odrive and ros2 control using [Articulated](https://github.com/joshnewans/articubot_one/tree/humble) Robotics. I am running everything on a laptop, no separate machines, on ROS2 humble. (BTW when I run the lidar and odrive on RPI the error get more often).

It shows perfectly fine when viewing the base_link frame, but with Odom the issue occurs.

The error:

```
[rviz2-4] [ERROR] [1681401743.264000589] [rviz2]: Lookup would require extrapolation into the future. Requested time 1681401743.323050 but the latest data is at time 1681401743.259460, when looking up transform from frame [laser_frame] to frame [map]
```

I changed the RPlidar pkg according this link, [Lookup would require extrapolation into the future on the same machine](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/24036/lookup-would-require-extrapolation-into-the-future-on-the-same-machine). It works intermittently but it often loses transform (I often get the error).